# Restore a remote dump to RDS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

I know how to restore a pg dump into a RDS database if that dump is in my machine, but how could I do it when the dump is available at a remote location, say Amazon S3?

What I want to do is something like this:

`pg_restore -h somedomain.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -p 5432 -d databasename -U username https://s3.amazonaws.com/database.dump`

But of course this results in

`pg_restore: [archiver] could not open input file "https://s3.amazonaws.com/database.dump"`

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If a filename is not specified, `pg_restore` will take data from standard input ([doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/app-pgrestore.html)). So, this would work:

`wget -O - 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/database.dump' | pg_restore -h somedomain.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -p 5432 -d databasename -U username`

Note that you can create an RDS snapshot, then create a new DB instance from that snapshot ([doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_RestoreFromSnapshot.html)). In your particular situation, I don't know if that would work better than backing up to S3, but it's worth mentioning.