# AWS lambda for automated restore from s3 to rds

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I have configured my on premise database server to put a backup everyday at 11 pm into aws s3. The backup is encrypted using s3 standard encryption.

I need to restore this encrypted postgresql backup from s3 to RDS (running postgres) as soon as it reaches the s3 and then query some fields and get the data using a python function which will send this data to list of emails.

My question is: can I use AWS lambda for this task instead of an ec2 instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In theory, yes you can, but there's some challenges ahead if you go down this path.

To restore the backup from S3 to postgresql: You will have to bundle the `pg_restore` or `psql` binaries into your Lambda deployment package. Your Lambda's code will then have to either download the backup S3 file to your Lambda's `/tmp` folder (watch out for Lambda's [limit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html) of 512 MB for the `/tmp` folder), or stream the S3 file's content to `pg_restore`/`psql` [via stdin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34139559/restore-a-remote-dump-to-rds). To invoke `psql` or `pg_restore`, you should use Python's [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module. Be careful with large backups not to load the whole backup file in memory: you could exceed Lambda's RAM limit.

To query the database, you'll want to include psycopg2 in your Lambda's deployment package. See https://github.com/jkehler/awslambda-psycopg2 for details on how to do that.

To send the data via email, you should look into using [AWS SES](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/?nc1=h_ls).

Personally, I would probably use a Docker container to achieve that (using AWS [ECS](https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/) or [Batch](https://aws.amazon.com/batch/)). This way, it will probably be easier to install the necessary binaries (`pg_restore`/`psql`, psycopg2). Also, you will avoid Lambda's inherent limitations (15 minutes execution time limit, max `/tmp` size, RAM limit).

Comment: Well explained. Thank you . Cheers!