# How run pg_restore for s3 folder?

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pg-restore

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34139980/1251549) is example about restoring postgres from s3 sigle file. It reads this file into stdout and redirects this strem into `pg_restore` tool. But what if there are several gz files on s3? Is there a way to make `pg_restore` read them **whihout** downloading into any temp folder?

**About loop restoring**

1. First of all it is unclear how postgress handle this situation. I have 50-100 `gz` files with different sizes. Yes they have a nems and can be sorted. But will postgres perform correct restore when I you only single file?

[image]

2. Also loop leads to donwload all files into some folder. Files can be big. So it it better to restore them from s3 directly.

Comment: We can't you just do that, only in a loop?  Do you know the names of the files ahead of time?

Comment: question has been updated.